# Integrating WSPBuilder projects in SourceSafe

Tags: 2007, wspbuilder, source-control

Is there a way to integrate WSPBuilder projects in SourceSafe? Is there any article regarding this on how to proceed?

Comment: WSP Builder shouldn't change the process of adding the project to source control.

Answer (score 1):

Like others are saying also, a WSP Builder project can just as easily be added to SourceSafe/TFS as any other project.

The steps to do this are:

1. File -> New -> Project
2. Choose a WSPBuilder Project
3. In the Solution Explorer of VS you right-click on the solution (or project, whatever you want).
4. Choose the option *Add Solution to Source Control*
5. Fill in your SourceSafe credentials in the appropriate box
6. Choose where you want to safe the current solution/project in the SourceSafe database and press OK

How to set up SourceSafe depends on how your organisation works. Perhaps reading up on some articles about different trees (trunk, branch, release) will be a good idea. I learned a lot by reading through some SVN documentation.
But that's really something out of the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

We add projects created by WSP Builder to TFS with out any issues. There should be no change to the process adding projects to any source control system.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like to add the WSP Builder onto my project manually.  Following are the steps that i use.

1. Copy following files onto the root of your SharePoint project in Visual Studio (2008).

   - CabLib.dll
   - Mono.Cecil.dll
   - WSPBuilder.exe
2. Add following post build script onto your Visual Studio project.

cd $(ProjectDir)
wspbuilder -outputpath Deployment -wspname mySharePointSolution.wsp  -CreateWSPFileList FileLog.txt -excludePaths "/bin/Debug;/bin"

Final step is to build your project and you should find your WSP file created.  Checkin allt he files onto TFS :)

Hope this helps

- Sudhir